# angular.js performance issues

Tags: angularjs

Batarang on the performance tab shows that on the app's root, angular is calling function that looks like that: 
`function (a){var e,f,i=a.$eval(h),m=hc(i,`.

According to batarang it's painfully slow and when I get little more rows on the app, it slows down the app and crashes Firefox (although Chrome still handles it). So what the heck is it doing? How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried using the unminified version so you can see more information?

Comment: it's calling ngRepeatWatch

Comment: it's starts by grabbing 80% of time, and slowly degrades, but never goes down to less than 50%

Comment: How many items are you repeating?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something to consider when building an Angular application where you're dynamically expanding the contents of an ngRepeat. Every ngRepeat you set up, sets up a watch. Every {{binding}} or ngModel you do inside of that repeat, sets up another watch, and so on. Each of those creates function and object instances, and also needs to be processed on every $digest. So, if your running into performance issues, you may need to implement a custom directive that writes out your data without setting up those superfluous watches, so you're a little more performant.  That my 2 cents.

Comment: can you tweak `ngrepeat`'s watch, so it would check for changes every defined number of seconds, without introducing custom directive?

Comment: Can you? Probably; JavaScript frameworks are extremely malleable.  I don't know that I would try though. You're probably going to be much better off with a custom directive, and it's likely to be a lot less work to write/maintain the custom directive than if you were going to alter something as core to Angular as the ngRepeat directive.

Comment: This answer is linked from other locations on SO but could really benefit from an example. I understand what you're saying, but without an example of how to implement a directive that outputs a complex template without creating additional watches, I'm a bit lost. Thanks!

Comment: @TylerForsythe, any example would be largely situational. But for argument's sake, basically you'd create a directive, that within the `link` function, dynamically built out DOM elements based on the model. Similar to what you'd do in a plain JQuery application. You'd then set up whatever ties you needed to do to update your model from the DOM and the DOM from your model. Probably with a single $watch, rather than n-$watches. ... if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're saying. Basically, instead of using a template full of {{ModelProperty}}, which creates watches, you'd build out the result manually via elements or a raw string. Time-consuming for a complex template, but the benefit is far fewer watches.

Comment: That's correct. And to be clear, I'd *only* do that in situations where performance was a problem.

Comment: Yup, only to improve performance, which I'm definitely having a problem with on one of my pages. Confirmed via Batarang and deleting the portion in question and noticing a speed bump. Further, there's no reason for the data within to have $watches all over it, only the main container. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

So I stumbled across this months after the question was asked when I was having what I think is a similar problem.  Let me describe my issue and my solution (that does not involve a directive) and you can see if it applies to yours.

I was building a table.  First I'd request the info telling me what rows were in the table, then I'd request more info that fills in the cells of the table.  So I'd get the first request and add all the rows to the table, then request the cell data. I'd fetch the cell data by row, but in a large table this would still be a lot of requests.  When I got the cell data back for that row, I'd fill it in.

This made for a really cool effect, all the cells with spinning icons waiting for data.  BUT, it made it really slow.  In Chrome, that was fine, the browser would slow down some, but it would continue to work.  But in FF, it would get that annoying "script busy or not responding" messsage.  If you clicked Continue it would work fine, but if you clicked "Cancel" you'd stop the script and nothing would work.

So, here's the solution I came up with.  No directive required.  All I did was build the data for each row completely, and only then add the row to the variable used by the ng-repeat.   This way it is MUCH faster.  The rows fill in as it gets all the data back, the $watch's are still there, but you are not triggering a ton of them at once and you can still have them to be able to change the data later (in my table you can edit each cell of the table so being able to change the data easily later was important).

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Yeah in my case it's turned out to be not angular's issue, but DOM's in general. You can't update too many elements at once, even if you put them in a queue, with limited number of elements, and update only few of them periodically, the process becomes continuous ($watch will keep adding elements to be updated). And updating DOM elements in any browser is still considerably slow, especially if you need to run some logic right before the update (e.g. datetime related), bad that javascript can't run in multiple threads

Comment: @Agzam: Actually, Javascript can run background threads... unless your users have IE <= 9. Which of course they do. As soon as everyone starts using a real browser though, this problem will be solved :)