# ngRepeatWatch seems to be a bottleneck in Batarang

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just noticed that [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) analyzing my AngularJS app shows the following:

`ngRepeatWatch | 64.2% | 136.0ms`

This is 10 times more time consuming that the next reported instructions.

Does that mean that I might be overusing `ngRepeat` directive? How to make sure?

Answer (score 4):

`ngRepeat` is quite slow for large sets because it creates a new scope for every item. I case you change a property in the repeated structure, the change is applies to the parent scope, etc. This makes creating a list slower.

Also applying filter and ranges does not make it better, try filter before you put the data into the template or depending on your data, do it on the server side.

If you do not need the changes pass to all scopes or the data does not change, try to create a directive for the element that should be repeated and make sure it does not inherit the parent scope.

Have you read:

- [ng-repeat with multiple filters on large data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126905/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-multiple-filters-on-large-data-set)
- [angular.js performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485828/angular-js-performance-issues)

Comment: I'm pretty satisfied with your answer. I'll leave the question open for a while, so that others can add some insights as well.
The only thing that I'm missing now is to answer myself that: how to know which `ng-repeat` is the bottleneck. This is very important, as I have a bunch of them and I can't start refactoring based just on my hunch, that it may be problematic.